# Is there a way to make glue job to always read data from xml as string?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have this xml which I am able to read and insert to RDS via AWS Glue. Below is the sample xml.

```
<VENDOR>
  <DETAILS>
    <RECORD>
      <VENDOR_NUMBER>123456D</VENDOR_NUMBER>
      <VENDOR_NAME>STORE 1</VENDOR_NAME>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
      <VENDOR_NUMBER>123456</VENDOR_NUMBER>
      <VENDOR_NAME>STORE 2</VENDOR_NAME>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
      <VENDOR_NUMBER>123456C</VENDOR_NUMBER>
      <VENDOR_NAME>STORE 3</VENDOR_NAME>
    </RECORD>
  </DETAILS>
  <TRAILER>
    <TOTAL_RECORD>00003</TOTAL_RECORD>
  </TRAILER>
</VENDOR>
```

For some reason the the column inside the dynamic frame created from the xml is always of struct type. Below is the printschema result and the sample code

```
datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "database", table_name = "table_name", transformation_ctx = "datasource")

datasource.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- VENDOR_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VENDOR_NUMBER: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- double: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- int: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- string: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to add a resolve choice to cast the data into string, it worked for int type, but didn't for the double type since the original data was **123456D**, but it somehow becomes a double **123456.0**. Below is the sample script and result in RDS.

```
resolvechoice = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = datasource, choice = "cast:string", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice")
```

```
VENDOR_NUMBER   VENDOR_NAME
123456.0        STORE 1
123456          STORE 2
123456G         STORE 3
```

I have also tried to update the schema of the table in the data catalog and change the data type of all the fields to string and also choose the option to ignore schema change in the glue crawler configuration option, but it didn't work. Below is from the crawler options

```
Configuration options
Schema updates in the data store        Ignore the change and don't update the table in the data catalog.
Inherit schema from table               Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table.
Object deletion in the data store       Mark the table as deprecated in the data catalog.
```

Is there a way to make glue job to always read data from xml as string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone in the AWS Forum answered my question. I'm posting the solution here just in case anyone needs it.

I used spark-xml to generate DataFrame instead of DynamicFrame.

```
df = spark.read.format('xml') \
    .option("rowTag", "RECORD") \
    .load("s3://bucket/glue/input-xml/")

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

```
root
 |-- VENDOR_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VENDOR_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)

+-----------+-------------+
|VENDOR_NAME|VENDOR_NUMBER|
+-----------+-------------+
|    STORE 1|      123456D|
|    STORE 2|       123456|
|    STORE 3|      123456C|
+-----------+-------------+
```

To do this, you need to download spark-xml JAR file, upload it to S3, and add it to the 'Dependent jars path' of the Glue job.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml_2.11/0.7.0
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/glue/latest/dg/add-job.html